# load an external swf (FlashPaper pdf) into a flash project

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, flash

I have to do a very simple `swf` application able to show a series of `pdf` files.
Actually I was able to create on a single layer the menu interface (some buttons on frame 0 which redirect the user to other frames where the pdf should be showed).

**Here my question:**

I need a way to read the pdf inside the flash frame.

I've found a possible solution converting the pdf into an swf with `FlashPaper 2`
Now I wish to know how import the swf into the frame.

Reading some actionscript 3 guides I was able to create a container movieclip (a simple rectangle) into which I have loaded the swf with this code:

```
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var defaultSWF:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.swf"); //test.swf is my converted pdf
loader.load(defaultSWF);

screen_01.addChild(loader); //screen_01 is the container rectangle converted to movieclip
```

I've used a container movieclip to mantain the other objects (menu buttons) on the frame, and ecause it helps with the swf positioning.
I seen it is possible also using `loader.x` and `loader.y` and it works.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to control width and height of the swf/pdf file (`loader.width` and `loader.height` exists but if used cause the swf will not loaded at all)

---

**Solution:**

I've found a possible solution at [this page](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?297261-Flash8-loadMovie-set-size-of-the-movie). 
 The idea is to change `swf` scale only after the load process is complete (positioning can be done even before).
Anyway I had to use `Actionscript 2` for this project because `FlashPaper` converted `pdf` doesn't work properly with `AS3`, I don't know why...

here the code:

```
//insert an emplty movieclip to load the swf, I've called it screen_01

var movLoad:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var myListener:Object = new Object();

myListener.onLoadInit = function(thisMc:MovieClip) {

    thisMc._height = 600;
    thisMc._width = 900;
    thisMc._x = 50;
    thisMc._y = 30;
};

movLoad.addListener(myListener);

movLoad.loadClip("folder/flashpaper_converted_pdf.swf.swf",screen_01);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the size of the loader using scaleX and scaleY properties.
Keep them equals so the swf isn't stretched.

You may also want to listen to the `COMPLETE` event to do such a thing :

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onComplete(e:Event)
{
    var loader:Loader = e.currentTarget.loader;

    loader.scaleX = loader.scaleY = 2; //Double the size of the loaded swf
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should be right (I've found a different solution, but I will test your on my next project). Anyway the problem was in the load timing. Position coordinates can be set before load the swf but scaling have to be performed after load is completed.